# ¿Por qué cuando uso position absolute se me traslapan las cajas?

Tags: html, css, nav

Estuve intentando hacer un menú desplegable utilizando css y html, pero me surgió un problema, y es que si uso position absolute se me traslapan las cajas, y si uso alguna como relative las cajas que no son parte del menú desplegable también bajan, lo cuál me imposibilita poder trabajar correctamente con el nav.

**HTML**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Abrazo de Oso | Inicio</title>
        <link rel="icon" href="resources/favicon.ico" type="image/x-icon">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="stylesheets/toolkit-nav.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="stylesheets/normalize.css">
        <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com"><link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com" crossorigin><link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Ubuntu:wght@300&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
        <script src="https://kit.fontawesome.com/4a3c81f854.js" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
    </head>
    <body>
        <header>
            <div class="toolkit-bar">
                <p class="toolkit-bar__text toolkitbar__content">¡Visita nuestras redes sociales!</p>
                <div class="toolkit-bar__icons toolkit-bar__content"><a href="https://www.instagram.com/abrazodeoso.peluches/" target="_BLANK"><i class="fab fa-instagram"></i></a></div>
                <div class="toolkit-bar__icons toolkit-bar__content"><a href="https://m.facebook.com/100083547669607/" target="_BLANK"><i class="fa-brands fa-square-facebook"></i></a></div>
                <div class="toolkit-bar__icons toolkit-bar__content"><a href="https://wa.me/+56984460812" target="_BLANK"><i class="fa-brands fa-whatsapp"></i></a></div>
            </div>
            <nav class="nav">
                <div class="nav__container-logo">
                        <div class="nav__logo">
                            <img src="resources/logo.png" alt="Logo">
                </div>
                <div class="nav__buttons">
                    <ul class="nav__buttons-container">
                        <li class="nav__buttons-item nav__item-categorias"><a href="#">Categorías</a>
                           <ul class="nav__buttons-item-submenu">
                               <li class="nav__buttons-item-submenu-li"><a href="#">Categoría 1</a></li>
                               <li class="nav__buttons-item-submenu-li"><a href="#">Categoría 2</a></li>
                               <li class="nav__buttons-item-submenu-li"><a href="#">Categoría 3</a></li>
                               <li class="nav__buttons-item-submenu-li"><a href="#">Categoría 4</a></li>
                           </ul>
                        </li>
                        <li class="nav__buttons-item nav__item-contacto"><a href="#">Contacto</a></li>
                        <li class="nav__buttons-item nav__item-informacion"><a href="#">Información</a></li>
                        <li class="nav__buttons-item nav__item-tendencia"><a href="#">Tendencias</a></li>
                    </ul>        
                </div>
            </nav>
        </header>
    </body>
</html>
```

**Fragmento CSS**

```
* {
    font-family: 'Ubuntu', sans-serif;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    text-decoration: none;

.nav {
    display: flex;
    background-color: rgb(253, 208, 234);
    box-shadow: 100px;
    box-shadow: 0px 5px 14px -4px rgba(0,0,0,0.75);
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 5px 14px -4px rgba(0,0,0,0.75);
    -moz-box-shadow: 0px 5px 14px -4px rgba(0,0,0,0.75);
}

.nav__container-logo {
    width: 100%;
    height: 150px;
    padding: 5px 0px;
    margin-top: -50px;
}

.nav__logo {
    padding-bottom: 20px;
}

.nav__logo img {
    width: 7%;
    position: relative;
    left: 50px;
    top: 46px;
    border-bottom: none;
    z-index: 100;
}

.nav__buttons-container{
    list-style-type: none;
    text-align: center;
    margin-right: 280px;
}

.nav__buttons-item {
    display: inline-block;
    text-align: center;
    margin-right: 40px;
}

.nav__buttons-item a {
    padding: 4px 50px 4px 10px;
    color: rgb(51, 51, 51);
    background-color: rgb(253, 208, 234);
    border-left: 3px solid rgb(250, 145, 227);
    text-decoration: none;
    font-weight: bold;
    text-align: center;
}

.nav__buttons-item a:hover {
    background-color: rgb(255, 222, 245);
    color: rgb(51, 51, 51);
}

.nav__buttons-item-submenu-li {
    display: none;
    position: relative;
    margin-top: 10px;
}

.nav__item-categorias:hover .nav__buttons-item-submenu-li {
    display: block;
}

.nav__item-categorias:hover .nav__buttons-item {
    position: relative;
}
```

También intenté cambiar algunas clases, pero tampoco me ha resultado totalmente, ¿Qué puedo hacer para resolver el problema? Cabe recalcar que también estoy utilizando normalize.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cuando pones **position: absolute** a un elemento este toma de referencia para posicionarse en el elemento padre con position: relative más cercano, si no se lo colocas a nada este se posicionará en referencia al body, pero si se le colocas el **position: relative** a uno de los padres como he puesto el ejemplo, el elemento absolute se posicionará con ese padre de referencia.

```css
.container {
  width: 500px;
  height: 500px;
  background-color: gray;
}
.padre1 {
  width: 300px;
  height: 300px;
  background-color: red;
}
.padre2 {
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  background-color: yellow;
  position: relative;
}

.elemento {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 20px;
  left: 20px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="padre1">
    <div class="padre2">
        <a href="#" class="elemento">Mi elemento</a>
    </div>
</div>
</div>
```

En el ejemplo está posicionado a 20px de abajo y 20px de izquierda dentro del padre2, si pones el **position: relative**  en el padre1, verás como toma de referencia ese div para posicionarse en su lugar correspondiente.

Seguramernte se te desplaza porque está tomando como referencia para posicionarse la caja que no toca.